# Html content partially parsed

Tags: android, html

I am parsing a Xml file using SAX Parser in which I have one tag,`<Panchanga>` which consists of html contents as shown below:

```
<Panchanga><table style='font-size:14px;'> <tr> <td ><img src='panchangaImg.png'> </td><td> </td> <td> ವಿಕೃತಿ ಸಂ|ರದ ವೃಶ್ಚಿಕ ಮಾಸ ದಿನ 21 ಸಲುವ ಮಾರ್ಗಶಿರ ಶುದ್ಧ‌ ಬಿದಿಗೆ 38||| ಗಳಿಗೆ</td> </tr> </table><p style=margin-left:8px; margin-top:0em; font-size:14px;' ><b> ಮಹಾ ನಕ್ಷತ್ರ :</b>ಜ್ಯೇಷ್ಠಾ</br><b> ನಿತ್ಯ ನಕ್ಷತ್ರ :</b>ಮೂಲಾ 29 ಗಳಿಗೆ</br><b> ಋತು : </b>ಹೇಮಂತ ಋತು</br><b> ರಾಹುಕಾಲ : </b>3.00-4.30 ಗಂಟೆ</br><b> ಗುಳಿಕ ಕಾಲ : </b>12.00-1.30 ಗಂಟೆ</br><b> ಸೂರ್ಯೋದಯ : </b>6.43 ಗಂಟೆ</br><b> ಸೂರ್ಯಾಸ್ತ : </b>6.02 ಗಂಟೆ</br><b> ದಿನ ವಿಶೇಷ : </b>ಚಂದ್ರದರ್ಶನ,ಉಡುಪಿ ಚಂದ್ರಮೌಳೀಶ್ವರ ರಥ</br></p></Panchanga>
```

I am retreiving the contents using:

```
panchanga = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.panchanga);
Log.d("TAGs", "" + taglist.getPanchangas());
panchanga.setTypeface(kannada, Typeface.BOLD);
panchanga.setText(Html.fromHtml("<table style='font-size:14px;'> <tr> <td ><img src='panchangaImg.png'> </td><td> </td> <td> à²µà²¿à²•à³ƒà²¤à²¿ à²¸à²‚|à²°à²¦ à²µà³ƒà²¶à³à²šà²¿à²• à²®à²¾à²¸ à²¦à²¿à²¨ 21 à²¸à²²à³à²µ à²®à²¾à²°à³à²—à²¶à²¿à²° à²¶à³à²¦à³à²§â€Œ à²¬à²¿à²¦à²¿à²—à³† 38||| à²—à²³à²¿à²—à³†</td> </tr> </table><p style=margin-left:8px; margin-top:0em; font-size:14px;' ><b> à²®à²¹à²¾ à²¨à²•à³à²·à²¤à³à²° :</b>à²œà³à²¯à³‡à²·à³à² à²¾</br><b> à²¨à²¿à²¤à³à²¯ à²¨à²•à³à²·à²¤à³à²° :</b>à²®à³‚à²²à²¾ 29 à²—à²³à²¿à²—à³†</br><b> à²‹à²¤à³ : </b>à²¹à³‡à²®à²‚à²¤ à²‹à²¤à³</br><b> à²°à²¾à²¹à³à²•à²¾à²² : </b>3.00-4.30 à²—à²‚à²Ÿà³†</br><b> à²—à³à²³à²¿à²• à²•à²¾à²² : </b>12.00-1.30 à²—à²‚à²Ÿà³†</br><b> à²¸à³‚à²°à³à²¯à³‹à²¦à²¯ : </b>6.43 à²—à²‚à²Ÿà³†</br><b> à²¸à³‚à²°à³à²¯à²¾à²¸à³à²¤ : </b>6.02 à²—à²‚à²Ÿà³†</br><b> à²¦à²¿à²¨ à²µà²¿à²¶à³‡à²· : </b>à²šà²‚à²¦à³à²°à²¦à²°à³à²¶à²¨,à²‰à²¡à³à²ªà²¿ à²šà²‚à²¦à³à²°à²®à³Œà²³à³€à²¶à³à²µà²° à²°à²¥</br></p>"));
```

Is this the right way? Because I am not getting the desired output.I get something like this:

[image]

How to get the images from the contents?

Answer (score 0):

The `<br>` elements in your code are wrong. You have `</br>` and it should be `<br />`. That could prevent your HTML from parsing fully and certainly mess up the layout.